# using JNDI lookup of properties to determine spring import

Tags: spring, jndi

I am trying to import a properties file to determine which import I need.
I have looked at the following and they don't seem to have the exact answer:

http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/15/spring-3-1-m1-unified-property-management/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520055/import-spring-config-file-based-on-property-in-properties-file

they are close but not exactly what I'm looking for.

```
<beans:bean id="propertiesResource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean"
    p:jndiName="java:comp/env/url/resource/avcs" p:defaultObject="classpath:avcs.properties"/>

<beans:bean id="properties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="location" ref="propertiesResource"/>
</beans:bean>

<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="propertiesResource" system-properties-mode="ENVIRONMENT"/>

<beans:import resource="applicationContext.${application.context.import}.xml"/>
```

So I need to use the JNDI look-up to get the file and then load the properties then import the specific application context.
If I were to use the property-placeholder with just a class path resource then all would be well I believe but in this situation I need to do the JNDI look up first, and it seem the orfer of precedence puts the import before the JNDI.

Any chance anyone out there has an answer for me?

I have a few other ideas but I just wanted to see if there was anyone that might already have tackled this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW I am using spring 3.1.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will have to do something like this . I haven't tested it but basically the setLocations method in PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer takes in an array of Resource(In our case UrlResource - http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/UrlResource.html) which in turn has a constructor with the file path .

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="mypropsfile1" jndi-name="myPropsFile1" default-value="file:///C:/defaultPath" resource-ref="true"/>
<jee:jndi-lookup id="mypropsfile2" jndi-name="myPropsFile2" resource-ref="true"/>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer" 
class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" depends-on="mypropsfile1,mypropsfile2">
  <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
  <property name="locations">
        <list>
           <bean class="org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource">
               <constructor-arg><ref bean="mypropsfile1"/></constructor-arg>
           </bean>
           <bean class="org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource">
               <constructor-arg><ref bean="myPropsFile2"/></constructor-arg>
           </bean>
        </list>

  </property>
</bean>
```

Check for this discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408441/using-a-jeejndi-lookup-string-inside-an-instance-of-propertyplaceholderconfigu/8414669#8414669) . The depends-on will help set the dependencies for a particular bean .

Comment: I ended up using the solution posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520055/import-spring-config-file-based-on-property-in-properties-file